# Titanium IOS Notification using Parse

Tags: notifications, parse-platform, titanium

I am able to register for Notification on Parse.com using REST API for IOS using the code available on Parse.com ,but I am Not Receiving Notification on My Device. I have submitted certificate on Parse too. Do I need to code something for sending Push Notification ? Any help is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the code in this answer on the parse forum, it is 2 years old so might not work anymore.
https://parse.com/questions/push-notifications-when-using-titanium

Comment: I am using the same code.I am able to register but not getting any notification on my device

Answer (score 0):

Finally Nailed it!!! Thanks Jeroen for your answer. I was just neglecting 'Send A Push' option at Parse.Once i used the option,all is working fine